# Handling events occurs by a Javascript SDK in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, events, sdk, event-handling

I'm using a Javascript SDK in my Angular 11 Application to integrate a payment gateway. When a cutomer finishes there payment, an event is occured according to the payment status by the SDK. I want to catch each events seperately in my Angular application and do some functions accordingly. Can someone help me to solve this.

Three evets are as follows.

- payhere.onCompleted
- payhere.onDismissed
- payhere.onError

putting the code inside a script tag didn't do the job for me.

```
<script>

    payhere.onCompleted = function onCompleted(orderId) {
        console.log("Payment completed. OrderID:" + orderId);
    };

  
    payhere.onDismissed = function onDismissed() {
        console.log("Payment dismissed");
    };


    payhere.onError = function onError(error) {
        console.log("Error:"  + error);
    };

  
</script>
```

Comment: I would ask the provider of the SDK to provide an Angular wrapper, however without that, you can probably wrap it yourself.  However, if those events are not firing there is something else going on w/ your use of this SDK unrelated to Angular.